# Get assembly version from .net class library COM visible doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, class-library

I made a class library, COM visible, in CSharp with Visual Studio 2010.
When I try to call this method:

```
    public string Version {
        get { return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(); }
    }
```

from VB6 client I obtain **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**. Other methods works properly.
From .NET client all works fine!

What's wrong?
Thanks, Luigi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns the assmebly that launched this .Net process (with `Main()`)

In an unmanaged process, it will return null.

To get the assembly containing your code, use `typeof(MyType).Assembly`.